# Topicality of questions about printing

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

The following question recently appeared:

[What binding and paper should be used on a self-printed novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/what-binding-and-paper-makes-for-good-reading)

The question is almost entirely concerned with how to bind and print a self-published book. As such, it has pretty much nothing to do with *writing*. I voted to close it as off-topic. Does anybody think that we should keep it open?

Comment: Two things: This forum is *Writers* SE not *Writing* SE and is ergo about individuals and not strictly about process. There are some good writers here and some not so good writers here. Good writers will have a chance in hell of getting published. Bad writers won't. And after you've poured a few years of your life into a novel that subsequently received several dozen rejection letters all you might want is just to fork out a few dollars just so you can hold your hard work in bookish form. I know, because I've met these people and had the privilege of designing and "printing" their books.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My view of Writers.SE is that it's appropriate not only for writers but also for related professions - publishing including. So editing, agency, career-work are all on topic - and so's the nitty-gritty of self-publishing (or, heck, operating a small press).

Since this is a concrete, well-formed question addressing a field of concern to publishers of many stripes, I'd say it's firmly on topic.

My one concern is that if OP is speaking of making a single copy of the book (or just a few copies, for personal use/friends), then describing this as "publishing" or even "self-publishing" is borderline at best. But I think answers to this naturally scale to be useful at least to the level of modest print runs, so I'm good with this.

Answer (score 3):

I would support @JedOlivers comment that this is a forum for writers, not just writing. So anything that is directly connected to the publishing process should be on topic - hence a few questions on self-publishing and on agents are potentially acceptable.

I suppose I would want to ask of any question raised "Does this address an issue many writers face?" Most of the issues writers face are writing related, but not all. Most writers face issues and questions around publishing, printing etc. Few around which of their publishers social events they should attend (as an example - this has not been asked, so I am not getting at anyone). And even that could be broadened into a more relevant question.